# Why this model can't overfit one example?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, overfitting-underfitting

I am practicing conv1D on TensorFlow 2.7, and I am checking a decoder I developed by checking if it will overfit one example. The model doesn't learn when trained on only one example and can't overfit this one example. I want to understand this strange behavior, please. This is the link to the notebook on colab [Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1orjldOWjx2BkNkcFmduk-c2GtfK2Yhgc?usp=sharing).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Dense, BatchNormalization 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ReLU, MaxPool1D, GlobalMaxPool1D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import numpy as np

def Decoder():
    inputs = Input(shape=(68, 3), name='Input_Tensor')

    # First hidden layer
    conv1 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, name='Conv1D_1')(inputs)
    bn1 = BatchNormalization(name='BN_1')(conv1)
    relu1 = ReLU(name='ReLU_1')(bn1)
      
    # Second hidden layer
    conv2 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, name='Conv1D_2')(relu1)
    bn2 = BatchNormalization(name='BN_2')(conv2)
    relu2 = ReLU(name='ReLU_2')(bn2)

    # Third hidden layer
    conv3 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, name='Conv1D_3')(relu2)
    bn3 = BatchNormalization(name='BN_3')(conv3)
    relu3 = ReLU(name='ReLU_3')(bn3)

    # Fourth hidden layer
    conv4 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=1, name='Conv1D_4')(relu3)
    bn4 = BatchNormalization(name='BN_4')(conv4)
    relu4 = ReLU(name='ReLU_4')(bn4)

    # Fifth hidden layer
    conv5 = Conv1D(filters=1024, kernel_size=1, name='Conv1D_5')(relu4)
    bn5 = BatchNormalization(name='BN_5')(conv5)
    relu5 = ReLU(name='ReLU_5')(bn5)

    global_features = GlobalMaxPool1D(name='GlobalMaxPool1D')(relu5)
    global_features = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, -1))(global_features)

    conv6 = Conv1D(filters=12, kernel_size=1, name='Conv1D_6')(global_features)
    bn6 = BatchNormalization(name='BN_6')(conv6)
    outputs = ReLU(name='ReLU_6')(bn6)
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs], name='Decoder')
    return model

model = Decoder()
model.summary()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
losses = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses)

n = 1
X = np.random.rand(n, 68, 3)
y = np.random.rand(n, 1, 12)

model.fit(x=X,y=y, verbose=1, epochs=30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is, that you have no basis to learn anything, so you can't overfit. In every epoch you have just one example which is used to adapt the weights of the network. So there is not enough time to adapt the weights for overfitting here.

So to get the result of overfitting you want to have the same data multiple times inside your training dataset so the weights can change enought to overfitt because you only change them just one small step per epoch.

A deeper look into the back propagation might help you to get a better understanding of the concept. [Click](https://medium.com/datathings/neural-networks-and-backpropagation-explained-in-a-simple-way-f540a3611f5e)

I took th liberty to adapt your [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1orjldOWjx2BkNkcFmduk-c2GtfK2Yhgc?usp=sharing) and enhanced the dataset as following:

```
n = 1
X = np.random.rand(n, 68, 3)
y = np.random.rand(n, 1, 12)

for i in range(0,10):
  X=np.append(X,X,axis = 0)
  y=np.append(y,y,axis = 0)
```

And the output would be:[image: Output training Overfitting]

Comment: Thank you very much @Fabian. What I was trying to do is check if my models works. What I know is decreasing data will make model overfits, so it leads to it is working and can generalize.

Comment: As far as I'm seeing the model is working. The question would be if you get the metrics that you would like. 
I think the "proper" way to check if your model is generalizing is using three seperate datasets...one for training, one for validation during training and one seperate for testing the model after training. This way you can see during training via the validation data and metrics if your model is generalizing. You should also look into cross validation to build a reliable modle.